# Gradle processResources corrupts .jks

Tags: gradle

I have what I hope is a simple question that I've had no luck finding an answer to.

I want to have the build.gradle file set the version in my Spring Boot application by replacing certain variables.  This works as advertised:

```
def tokens = [
    "version": 'project.version.toString()',
    "projectName": project.name,
    "groupId": rootProject.group,
    "artifactId": project.name
]
processResources{
    filter (ReplaceTokens, tokens: tokens)
    outputs.upToDateWhen{ false }
}
```

This code, however, also replaces something in the java key store which I also include in my resources, which corrupts it.  When I use ant matchers to exclude anything that's not the file I want to replace, nothing else gets copied. i.e. include '*.properties'

Is there a way to only do the token replacement on certain files while still copying the rest of the files in the resource directory?  Do I need to define a separate copy task for non-property files?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? @blur0224?

Comment: I have not.  I ended up going a different direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to skip any binary files while the task `processReousrces` is executed. For instance, I use `expand()` to replace tokens in text files with values computed in the gradle script. So,

1. Skip the jks file
2. Move it to the binary resources

Here's how I can skip the files under the directory `src/main/resources/certs/`. The `doLast()` guarantees that the jks file is copied to the appropriate location when it finishes with the resources.

```
ext {
  commit = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
  branch = 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
}

/**
 * Processes the resources, excluding the certs while building.
 */
processResources {
  // Exclude the certs files to be processed as text
  exclude "**/certs/*"

  expand(
    timestamp: new Date(),
    commit: commit,
    branch: branch,
    version: project.version
  )

  // Copy the jks file to the resources (classpath)
  doLast {
    copy {
      from "src/main/resources/certs/server.jks"
      into "$buildDir/classes/main/certs"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, saved me a lot of time. For the maven users out there, you might need to put your .jks into the `sr/main/resources folder` and change `into "$buildDir/classes/main/certs"` to `into "$buildDir/resources/main"`

Answer (score 0):

```
processResources {
    filesNotMatching("**/certs/*") {
       expand(
         timestamp: new Date(),
         commit: commit,
         branch: branch,
         version: project.version
       )
    }
}
```

I got the same problem today and I found this solution on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36731250/2611959