# How to filter a single resource in Gradle (like filter in Maven)

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to filter (i.e. do variable replacement) a single Java properties file using Gradle.

I have this in my gradle.build file:

```
tasks {
  processResources {
    expand(project_version: project.version)
  }
}
```

But, this attempts to filter all the files in the project resources directory, which causes problems*.  How can I configure `processResources` to:

- Do variable replacement for just a single file, say 'version.properties'
- Not do replacement in other resource files
- Still process the other resource files normally by copying them over to the output directory?

Thank you in advance,

--ee

* What problems you may ask?  Well, some of the files *look* like they should have variable replacement done - they have values like `$some_value` in them.  The templating processor sees the `$some_value` expression thinks it should have a value to insert, but it doesn't, so it errors out the build.

Comment: I believe you're looking for `filesMatching("<pattern>") { expand(...) }`.

Comment: @Slaw - That was it!  Thank you for the quick answer.  I'd accept your answer, but its a comment.

Comment: Yes, I decided not to write an answer because I was pretty sure this question was a duplicate, but I didn't have time to search so I left a comment to at least give you a solution. Anyway, the Q&A I was thinking of is [How to expand property references in jar resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17274107/6395627). One of the two top-voted answers solves your question. Not sure if your question is a proper duplicate of it though.